# SQL Server 2008: Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting, floating-point, nvarchar

Presently troubleshooting a problem where running this SQL query:

```
UPDATE tblBenchmarkData 
SET OriginalValue = DataValue, OriginalUnitID = DataUnitID, 
    DataValue = CAST(DataValue AS float) * 1.335 
WHERE 
    FieldDataSetID = '6956beeb-a1e7-47f2-96db-0044746ad6d5' 
    AND ZEGCodeID IN 
             (SELECT ZEGCodeID FROM tblZEGCode 
              WHERE(ZEGCode = 'C004') OR 
                   (LEFT(ZEGParentCode, 4) = 'C004'))
```

Results in the following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

The really odd thing is, if I change the `UPDATE` to `SELECT` to inspect the values that are retrieved are numerical values:

```
SELECT DataValue 
FROM tblBenchmarkData 
WHERE FieldDataSetID = '6956beeb-a1e7-47f2-96db-0044746ad6d5' 
AND ZEGCodeID IN 
         (SELECT ZEGCodeID 
          FROM tblZEGCode WHERE(ZEGCode = 'C004') OR 
                               (LEFT(ZEGParentCode, 4) = 'C004'))
```

Here are the results:

```
DataValue
2285260
1205310
```

Would like to use `TRY_PARSE` or something like that; however, we are running on SQL Server 2008 rather than SQL Server 2012. Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the schema definition of tblBenchmarkData, but you could try using ISNUMERIC in your query.  Something like:

```
SET DataValue = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(DataValue)=1 THEN CAST(DataValue AS float) * 1.335 
                     ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 2):

Order of execution not always matches one's expectations.

If you set a `where` clause, it generally does not mean the calculations in the `select` list will only be applied to the rows that match that `where`. SQL Server may easily decide to do a bulk calculation and then filter out unwanted rows.

That said, you can easily write try_parse yourself:

```
create function dbo.try_parse(@v nvarchar(30))
returns float
with schemabinding, returns null on null input
as
begin
  if isnumeric(@v) = 1
    return cast(@v as float);

  return null;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

So starting with your update query that's giving an error (please forgive me for rewriting it for my own clarity):

```
UPDATE B
SET
   OriginalValue = DataValue,
   OriginalUnitID = DataUnitID,
   DataValue = CAST(DataValue AS float) * 1.335
FROM
   dbo.tblBenchmarkData B
   INNER JOIN dbo.tblZEGCode Z
      ON B.ZEGCodeID = Z.ZEGCodeID
WHERE
   B.FieldDataSetID = '6956beeb-a1e7-47f2-96db-0044746ad6d5'
   AND (
      Z.ZEGCode = 'C004' OR 
      Z.ZEGParentCode LIKE 'C004%'
   )
```

I think you'll find that a SELECT statement with exactly the same expressions will give the same error:

```
SELECT
   OriginalValue,
   DataValue NewOriginalValue,
   OriginalUnitID,
   DataUnitID OriginalUnitID,
   DataValue,
   CAST(DataValue AS float) * 1.335 NewDataValue
FROM
   dbo.tblBenchmarkData B
   INNER JOIN dbo.tblZEGCode Z
      ON B.ZEGCodeID = Z.ZEGCodeID
WHERE
   B.FieldDataSetID = '6956beeb-a1e7-47f2-96db-0044746ad6d5'
   AND (
      Z.ZEGCode = 'C004' OR 
      Z.ZEGParentCode LIKE 'C004%'
   )
```

This should show you the rows that can't convert:

```
SELECT
    B.*
 FROM
    dbo.tblBenchmarkData B
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblZEGCode Z
       ON B.ZEGCodeID = Z.ZEGCodeID
 WHERE
    B.FieldDataSetID = '6956beeb-a1e7-47f2-96db-0044746ad6d5'
    AND (
       Z.ZEGCode = 'C004' OR 
       Z.ZEGParentCode LIKE 'C004%'
    )
    AND IsNumeric(DataValue) = 0
    -- AND IsNumeric(DataValue + 'E0') = 0 -- try this if the prior doesn't work
```

The trick in the last commented line is to tack on things to the string to force only valid numbers to be numeric. For example, if you wanted only integers, `IsNumeric(DataValue + '.0E0') = 0` would show you those that aren't.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  One problem I also experienced was that if the data is in scientific notation, the CAST doesn't work.  So to fix that problem executing a database view that changes all numbers from scientific to standard notation, e.g., DataValue
2.86777e+006
5.43724e+006

Comment: Aha, if you actually have scientific notation already then my trick with tacking on 'E0' won't work. But the IsNumeric function should still be able to help you.