# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric. Error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know there might be several reference to the error which I mentioned in question, but seriously I tried and it didn't worked for me.

I have a code which works when is for `adding menu dynamically`. So, if the menu is in the Root, its `Parent_Mkey` will always be 0. All works fine but when I debug the below line

```
MainEnqMkey = InsertUpdateDelete.InsertUpdateDeleteCls.InsertUpdateDelete_sql(strMode, strMkey, "WMS_Menu_Hdr", "MKEY", "MEH", StrPubBldg.ToString());
```

I get error as

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Here is my code below

```
public bool Save()
{
    int strMkey;
    if (txt_menu_name.Value == "" && txt_url_name.Text == "" && HidSelNode.Value != "0")
    {
        strMode = "M";
        strMkey = Convert.ToInt32(HidSelNode.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        strMode = "A";
        strMkey = 0;
    }
    if (1 == 1)
    {
        SqlConnection ObjPriCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConn"].ToString());
        ObjPriCon.Open();

        StringBuilder StrPubBldg = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(StrPubBldg);
        xw.WriteStartElement("DocumentElement");
        xw.WriteStartElement("WMS_Menu_Hdr");
        xw.WriteElementString("DELETE_FLAG", "N");
        if (strMode == "M")
        {
            xw.WriteElementString("MENU_NAME", txt_selnode.Text);
            xw.WriteElementString("URL", txt_selurl.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            string result;
            string strquery = "select max(order_by) +10 order_by from WMS_Menu_Hdr where PARENT_MKEY=@PARENT_MKEY";
            SqlCommand ObjPriCmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, ObjPriCon);
            if (HidSelNode.Value == "0")
            {
                ObjPriCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARENT_MKEY", HidSelNode.Value);
                result = ObjPriCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                ObjPriCmd = new SqlCommand("select ISNULL(a.order_by, max(b.order_by) +10) next_orderby " +
                                  " from WMS_Menu_Hdr b," +
                                 "(select max(order_by) +10 order_by from WMS_Menu_Hdr  where PARENT_MKEY= '" + HidSelNode.Value + "') a " +
                                 " where mkey='" + HidSelNode.Value + "' group by a.order_by", ObjPriCon);
                strquery = ObjPriCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            xw.WriteElementString("MENU_NAME", txt_menu_name.Value);
            xw.WriteElementString("URL", txt_url_name.Text);
            xw.WriteElementString("CREATION_DATE", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
            xw.WriteElementString("PARENT_MKEY", HidSelNode.Value);
            xw.WriteElementString("ORDER_BY", strquery);
        }

        xw.WriteEndElement();
        xw.Close();

        MainEnqMkey = InsertUpdateDelete.InsertUpdateDeleteCls.InsertUpdateDelete_sql(strMode, strMkey, "WMS_Menu_Hdr", "MKEY", "MEH", StrPubBldg.ToString());
    }
    if (MainEnqMkey.Equals(0))
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessScript", "alert('Some Error Occured While Saving Data !!')", true);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please suggest what is wrong here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161264/arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-varchar-to-data-type-numeric-10-9-00

Comment: What is `MainEnqMkey` and what returns `InsertUpdateDelete_sql`?

Comment: So where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: Error is inside `InsertUpdateDelete_sql`.. We need to see it's implementation..

Comment: @Vladimirs: `MainEnqMkey` is my string which returns value fetched from `InsertUpdateDelete_sql`

Comment: Are you missing a second `WriteEndElement` call?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: where should i m missing it ??

Comment: Ok so you inserting something wrong then.. We need to see `WMS_Menu_Hdr` definition

Comment: @Vladimirs: what exactly do you want ?? table structure  or something else?

Comment: You have two `xw.WriteStartElement` calls at the top but only one `xw.WriteEndElement` at the bottom. You need to add a second `xw.WriteEndElement` call at the same location to balance out the `xw.WriteStartElement` calls.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: so where should I end the second `WriteEndElement` ?

Comment: @coder Right before the call to `Close()`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: yes now that error didn't came, but in`Sr_no` from the table the value went as **NULL** why ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Is this related to connection string ? `"<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SessionWarning"].ToString()%>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that your `PARENT_MKEY` is `numeric`, but you inserting `'0'` which is `varchar`.

I believe that SQL should look like (`'0'` => `0`):

```
insert into WMS_Menu_Hdr (MKEY,DELETE_FLAG,MENU_NAME,URL,CREATION_DATE,PARENT_MKEY,ORDER_BY) values(44,'N','WMS Root','test.aspx','01-12-2015 04:51:40',0,'select max(order_by) +10 order_by from WMS_Menu_Hdr where PARENT_MKEY=@PARENT_MKEY')
```

**Update.**

Also your `ORDER_BY` field is `numeric` when you inserting `varchar`. So you need either to think of a number that will represent `select max(order_by) +10 order_by from WMS_Menu_Hdr where PARENT_MKEY=@PARENT_MKEY` or change type of `ORDER_BY` to `varchar`

Comment: i tried with **0** also but still getting the same error

Comment: one more thing here, i am not inserting `sr_no` and in table also its getting as NULL, `N` is my `delete_flag`

Comment: @coder I deleted my previous comment as it was wrong (too confused with way how you dumping all data - is not very readable), anyway another problem is in `ORDER_BY` it is also `numeric` when you inserting `varchar` (`'select max(order_by) +10 order_by from WMS_Menu_Hdr where PARENT_MKEY=@PARENT_MKEY'`)

Comment: ohh, so can you update your answer for `ORDER_BY` part so that I can edit and check

Comment: @coder Updated my answer, however it is up to you how you going to solve this as I am not aware how this field used in other part of your system (but it looks like it just a wrong type).

Comment: ok, let me think.. what can be the easiest way to achieve it.

Comment: the main error was the closing of `WriteEndElement` which was mentioned by `dasblinkenlight` and mostly it resolved my error.