# SQL Execution Error. Error converting data type nvarchar to real

Tags: c#, sql

Presently I am troubleshoot a SQL Server 2008 query that started failing.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.tblBenchmarkData.FieldDataSetID, dbo.tblBC.BCID, CAST(dbo.tblBenchmarkData.DataValue AS float(8)) AS DataValue, 
                  dbo.tblBC.BCMnemonic, dbo.tblDataType.DataTypeMnemonic
FROM         dbo.tblFieldDataSet RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblBenchmarkData ON dbo.tblFieldDataSet.FieldDataSetID = dbo.tblBenchmarkData.FieldDataSetID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblBC LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblDataType ON dbo.tblBC.DataTypeID = dbo.tblDataType.DataTypeID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblZEGCode ON dbo.tblBC.BCID = dbo.tblZEGCode.BCID ON dbo.tblBenchmarkData.ZEGCodeID = dbo.tblZEGCode.ZEGCodeID
WHERE     (dbo.tblDataType.DataTypeID = '{5951994B-BF47-4117-805D-B8F85FAB76A8}') AND (dbo.tblFieldDataSet.OriginalFieldDataSetID IS NULL) AND 
                  (dbo.tblFieldDataSet.Duplicate = 0)
ORDER BY dbo.tblBC.BCMnemonic, DataValue
```

When I remove the cast and execute the query it returns about 1 400 000 rows, so I take the DataValue results and run a small C# program against this output to verify that all the data is in fact numeric:

```
List<String> lstLinesOfFile = new List<string>();
Int64 intLineCounter = 0;
ReadFile("data.txt");
double dblNum;

foreach (string strValue in lstLinesOfFile)
{
   bool isNum = double.TryParse(strValue, out dblNum);

   if (!isNum)
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("Line: " + Convert.ToString(intLineCounter) + ", Value = " + strValue);
   }
   intLineCounter++;
}
```

The program indicates that there are no data rows that are not numeric, so does anyone have any suggestions as to why I would be receiving this error?  TIA.

UPDATE:
Here is the code I wrote to verify that it was checking every line of data:

```
List<String> lstLinesOfFile = new List<string>();
Int64 intLineCounter = 0;
ReadFile("data.txt");
double dblNum;

foreach (string strValue in lstLinesOfFile)
{
   bool isNum = double.TryParse(strValue, out dblNum);

   if (!isNum)
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("Line: " + Convert.ToString(intLineCounter) + ", Value = " + strValue);
   }
   else
   {
       Debug.WriteLine("Line: " + Convert.ToString(intLineCounter) + ", Number = " + strValue);
   }
   intLineCounter++;
}
```

This gives results like:

```
....

Line: 241564, Number = 1843.2
Line: 241565, Number = 18430
Line: 241566, Number = 18430.9
Line: 241567, Number = 18431.6
Line: 241568, Number = 18433.9
Line: 241569, Number = 1844.52

....
```

UPDATE 2:
Pasted code above from the full original view.

Comment: Didn't you ask almost the same question a year ago with the same table? Does the answer you accepted still not help (ie search for rows based on ISNUMERIC)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136722/sql-server-2008-error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-float

Comment: When I try using the CASE WHEN like I did there I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.tblBenchmarkData.FieldDataSetID, dbo.tblBC.BCID... is actually a view called qryFieldParameterBCNumericLookup.  When I execute this command:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MyDatabase.dbo.qryFieldParameterBCNumericLookup
```

I get the error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to real.
```

When I execute any of these commands, they work perfectly fine with no errors:

```
SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.dbo.qryFieldParameterBCNumericLookup
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM MyDatabase.dbo.qryFieldParameterBCNumericLookup
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM MyDatabase.dbo.qryFieldParameterBCNumericLookup
```

Comment: There are two things I'd suggest.  First, TOP is a function in 2008.  Meaning you can do `SELECT TOP(100) * FROM xxx`.  Try that.  Second, send your table and view definitions to sql server support and ask them what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to figure out which values cannot be parsed by SQL

```
select * from tblBenchData where ISNUMERIC(DataValue) = 0
```

or this

```
select * from tblBenchData where DataValue like '%[a-Z]%'
```

My guess would be a culture issue (e.g. "," vs ".")

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  This query returns zero rows, so I'm perplexed.

Comment: It still returns zero rows with the [a-Z].

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because there are a surprising number of odd strings that will pass the `ISNUMERIC()` test but that will fail to `CAST()` to float (and may still be convertible by `double.TryParse`).  Three that I know of offhand are:

- '+'
- '.'
- '-'

Here's one way to catch some of these:

```
SELECT DataValue
FROM   dbo.tblBenchData
WHERE  ISNUMERIC('0'+DataValue) = 0
```

And strangely, this will either correctly convert or else reject most of them without error:

```
SELECT CAST('0'+DataValue As float(8)) As DataValue
FROM   dbo.tblBenchData
WHERE  ISNUMERIC('0'+DataValue) = 0
```

There's still a few odd cases that can get through though.

---

OK, I had forgotten that this trick does not like valid negative values.

And, as for the "other" odd cases, I really cannot remember them all, nor have I ever seen them listed anywhere (really annoying, I know).  However, most of the problem strings come from how the various different numeric parsers view so-called "degenerate cases", that is, single character strings.

So one way to try to address both of these problems would be to pre-check for strings whose length is  one, and then handle them specially.  So, changing you original query to something like this should work:

```
;WITH cteBench As
(
    SELECT  *
        ,   CASE
                WHEN DataValue IN('-','.','+')  THEN '0'
                WHEN Len(DataValue) = 1 AND DataValue BETWEEN '0' And '9'
                                                THEN DataValue
                WHEN Len(DataValue) = 1         THEN ''
                WHEN DataValue LIKE '-%'        THEN DataValue
                ELSE                    '0'+DataValue
            END As FixedDataValue
    FROM    dbo.tblBenchmarkData.DataValue
)
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT cteBench.FieldDataSetID, dbo.tblBC.BCID, CAST(cteBench.FixedDataValue AS float(8)) AS DataValue, 
                  dbo.tblBC.BCMnemonic, dbo.tblDataType.DataTypeMnemonic
FROM         dbo.tblFieldDataSet RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  cteBench ON dbo.tblFieldDataSet.FieldDataSetID = cteBench.FieldDataSetID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblBC LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblDataType ON dbo.tblBC.DataTypeID = dbo.tblDataType.DataTypeID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblZEGCode ON dbo.tblBC.BCID = dbo.tblZEGCode.BCID ON cteBench.ZEGCodeID = dbo.tblZEGCode.ZEGCodeID
WHERE     (dbo.tblDataType.DataTypeID = '{5951994B-BF47-4117-805D-B8F85FAB76A8}')
 AND      (dbo.tblFieldDataSet.OriginalFieldDataSetID IS NULL)
 AND      (dbo.tblFieldDataSet.Duplicate = 0)
 AND      ISNUMERIC(FixedDataValue) = 1
ORDER BY dbo.tblBC.BCMnemonic, DataValue
```

Comment: Yes, that is the problem--all the values that are negative are being returned by your query!

Comment: Please provide further details on the few odd cases that can get through.

Comment: Thanks for the cteBench table expression.  It still returns an error.  For reasons I can't explain, executing the query with TOP 100 causes the error, while any other number works fine.

Comment: There's probably an additional odd string in the column towards the end of your data order that's not being caught by my filter.  These things can be a real headache to find.

Answer (score 1):

You have a right outer and left outer join syntax in that query; but you are using a where clause on the right/left joined tables.  That's kind of nasty and probably not doing what you expect.

I'd start with seeing what DataSetID is coming back as null in the `tblBenchData` table.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblDataSet
  WHERE DataSetID NOT EXISTS IN (SELECT DataSetID FROM tblBenchData)
```

Next, I'm guessing you missed something on your copy/paste because there is no `ON` condition for the left outer join on `tblBenchCode`.  Could you provide the actual query in use?

Side note: I'm not entirely certain why you have the `TOP(100) PERCENT` piece.  I know it was an unreliable trick to allow order by in view definitions, but it's meaningless today and certainly meaningless in the query you provided... unless this is an ancient SQL server.

---

Another possibility is, as Loud pointed out, your question from a year ago indicated you had values that were in [scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136951/2424)...

Comment: I checked the scientific notation, and there aren't any in this case.  Please see update 2 for the full view.

Comment: FYI, the TOP 100 PERCENT is put in automatically by SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like you are not hooking up the c# code to the sql query.

The line below sets 1stLinesOffline to a empty list of string but you never set it to anything else so the for loop will never run.

List lstLinesOfFile = new List();

I'd expect to see

List 1stLinesOfFile = mySqlResults;

where mySqlResults is the result dataset of your SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Actually, I just copied and pasted the results from SSMS and read that data in using a the function I created ReadFile("data.txt");  When I ran the c# project in visual studio I verified that it checked all 1.4 million rows of data.  Please see the my update for details.