# Conversion failed when converting the varchar "x" value to data type int SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I have this query :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM STUDENTS 
 WHERE STUDENT_ID NOT IN 
       (SELECT STD_VALUE 
          FROM PROVIDERS_STD 
         WHERE STD_TYPE = 'STUDENT')
```

I have the following error :

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar "x" value to data type
>   int.

The error isn't always shown and on the same computers. I mention this query is used in ASP.NET Webforms C# project.

parametrize

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome. Be sure to include the `CREATE TABLE` scripts for `STUDENTS` and `PROVIDERS_STD`.

Comment: Since `x` is definitely not an integer, the problem is obvious. It's probably because `Student_ID` is an integer but `STD_VALUE` is a string field that contains random data

Comment: Is there any value of type varchar with value "x" in either of the columns STUDENT_ID or STD_VALUE?

Comment: theoretically. the subquery filters the results to int values, but the query throws error like there isn't a condition in the subquery - STD_TYPE ='STUDENT'

Comment: " the subquery filters the results to int values"...does it, how? I would guess you have some value in `STD_VALUE` which isn't an integer (or perhaps the other way round, a value in `STUDENT_ID` which isn't an integer). If you're going to match two fields to each other, it makes a lot more sense if they are both of the same data type. If your Providers table contains IDs/values which are mix of types, that's probably a symptom of a poor schema design.

Comment: The *actual* problem is probably caused by the `Providers_STD` table itself. Such tables that mix up different kinds of data in a single `key/value` form are a bad idea. You just found *one* of the problems. The other serious issues is that the data can't be validated, sorted or indexed. You can't ensure that the field contains valid numbers when it can easily contain names.

Comment: the column STD_VALUE has only int values for condition STD_TYPE = 'STUDENT'

Comment: @CristinaAnton It's [perfectly possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136783/11683) for the server to choose an execution plan where all values are converted to int first and only then filtered out on `STD_TYPE = 'STUDENT'`. So yes, it's as if "there isn't a condition in the subquery". Try using [`try_cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @CristinaAnton are you *sure*? Where did that `x` come from then? In any case, *don'* use such tables. A quick&dirty fix for just this case (mixed types) would be to use separate fields per type, although that still won't allow you to specify constraints, index, sort or perform range queries.

Comment: Have you considered casting the `int` to `nvarchar`? I mean, your index lookups are going to suck regardless - so they may as well suck in a way that won't throw an exception.

Comment: @CristinaAnton if `STD_TYPE` isn't indexed and the rows too few, the server may decide to scan the entire table and filter the values at the end. The server has no idea that the field contains mixed values, it knows only what you told it - that this is a string column, and that you want to compare it with an `int` column

Comment: @GSerg this is what I also believe it's the real problem

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 may also be worth a read if you really want to convert the `nvarchar` to `int`.

Comment: @mjwills casting is a solution. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are accessing tables and not views, this would only happen if `STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID` and `PROVIDES_STD.STD_VALUE` have different types, one a number, and one a string.

I am not a fan of `NOT IN` with a subquery, because it doesn't work intuitively in the presence of `NULL`s.  So, I would phrase the query with an explicit conversion:

```
SELECT S.* 
FROM STUDENTS S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM PROVIDERS_STD P
                  WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, P.STD_VALUE) = S.STUDENT_ID AND
                        P.STD_TYPE = 'STUDENT'
                 );
```

Notice that I'm converting to a number, rather than to a string.  Just a couple weeks ago, I noticed a bug in some code . . . due to zero padding of string values in a similar situation.

Answer (score -1):

If any records get returned from below query, you need to exclude them.

```
SELECT STD_VALUE FROM PROVIDERS_STD where STD_TYPE ='STUDENT' 
AND ISNUMERIC(STD_VALUE) = 0
```

It is because the value from `STD_VALUE` cannot be implicit converted to `int`. (as well as explicit)

Comment: The OP says that `where STD_TYPE ='STUDENT'` already guarantees the `STD_VALUE` is numeric. Even if it was not, the issue is that the server decides to [change the order of evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792540/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-x-value-to-data-type-int-sql#comment100139855_56792540), at which point it could just as easily decide to apply `where ISNUMERIC(STD_VALUE) = 0` after attempting to convert the `STD_VALUE` to int, and this change won't do anything.

Comment: but if all the value is `INT`, where does `x` come from?

Comment: From records where `STD_TYPE <> 'STUDENT'`.